# how to combine these two codes under one method? (rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to combine these two codes inside the controller into one under "create"

```
class PostcommentsController < ApplicationController

   def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
    @comment = Postcomment.new(params[:postcomment])
    @comment.micropost = @micropost
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
       redirect_to(:back)
    else
      render partial: 'shared/_postcomment_form', locals: { micropost: @micropost }
    end
  end

  def create2
    @discussion = Discussion.find(params[:discussion_id])
    @comment = Postcomment.new(params[:postcomment])
    @comment.discussion = @discussion
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
       redirect_to(:back)
    else
      render partial: 'shared/_postcomment_form', locals: { discussion: @discussion }
    end
  end
end
```

I tried both codes under "create" and they work. 
I have two models that I'm associating postcomment to: micropost and discussion. 
I want to apply the correct "create" depending on if it's a micropost or discussion.

Here's what I'm using in view for discussion

```
<%= form_for([@discussion, @comment]) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :comment_content %>
<button class="btn" type="submit">
Comment
</button>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give it a "blind" try cause I don't have access to my environment right now so it won't be tested code, let me know if it works or hangs somewhere...:

```
def create
  model = params.has_key?(:micropost_id) ? Micropost : Discussion
  @object = model.find(params[model.to_s.foreign_key.to_sym])
  @comment = Postcomment.new(params[:postcomment])
  @comment.write_reflection(@object)
  @comment.user = current_user
  if @comment.save
     redirect_to(:back)
  else
    render partial: 'shared/_postcomment_form', locals: { model.to_s.downcase.to_sym => @object }
  end
end
```

And in your Comment model:

```
def write_reflection(object)
  if object.kind_of?(Micropost)
    self.micropost = object
  else
    self.discussion = object
  end
end
```

Comment: I got this error: `SyntaxError in PostcommentsController#create' 'syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
  @comment.send(model.to_s.downcase) = @object`

Comment: any idea how the code should be updated? I really appreciate the help

Comment: for some reason, I got this error: `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in PostcommentsController#create`. `Discussion(#63531588) expected, got Micropost(#46911096)`. This happened when I tried to create a new comment for "micropost"

Comment: it refers to the postcomment model in "write_reflection" for line 19 which is  `self.discussion = object`, and also refers to line 17 in the postcomment controller which is `@comment.write_reflection(@object)`

Comment: Oooooops, totally my fault, ok so I edited my answer the line that changed is that one `if object.kind_of?(Micropost)` it was always false cause `object.class.class` is actually... **Class**, now this should work : )

Comment: @Sparda it's great that you answered the question, but perhaps you should tell the user why this is a horrible idea?

Comment: You are totally right, but globally I prefer answer the questions rather than giving advice, or doing both but ALWAYS provide a working answer whatever I think because 9 times out of 10 this is what people want because they already thought about what they need, we don't and can't possibly know the reasons behind these choices

Comment: I read over your answer Mohamad so I will look into polymorphic associations in the future. In the meantime, I have `def new` inside the postcomment controller as `@micropost = Micropost.new(params[:micropost])`, do I need to update this?

Comment: In your comments controller, then only thing that the `new` method should be creating is an instance of `Postcomment`, so `@comment = Postcomment.new`. This way the create methods creates it from `params[:comment]` I'm not sure why you are creating a new `Micropost` instance there. I can't think of a good reason, but if you have one,  share it. I can't help but emphasise that what you are doing is here very wrong. The alternatives are easier. That's why we have conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Sparda already answered this question, so I wont repeat his answer.

But I want to tell you that this is a very bad idea. It's not a good way of doing things. You should use Polymorphic Associations to represent the comments relationship with discussions and microposts.

You are setting yourself up for needless refactoring if things change in the future.

You have to ask yourself what are you trying to achieve by combining the two actions? What if one day you add another model?

```
def create
  model = params.has_key?(:micropost_id) ? Micropost : Discussion

def create
  model = case params
  when params.has_key?(:foo) then foo
  ... # where do you stop?
```

You also have to repeat this in your `new` action to create the correct objects and avoid `nil class` errors.

This is not a sane way of doing things.

Check this out: http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised (requires subscription)

Or this older but free episode: http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association